# Google Chrome not offering to save passwords

Tags: google-chrome

My co-worker is using Google Chrome but cannot get it to offer to save his passwords.

He is on XP with Chrome version 6.0.472.63

I made sure that "offer to save passwords" is selected in options and cleared all his browsing data. It still won't offer.

I am using the same version of Chrome on Win7 and it saves my passwords for the same sites.

I am not sure what else to try?

Comment: Can you try upgrading it to the latest version? Stable build is now at V8.0.552.215

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Chrome will never offer to save passwords for protected directories, nor will any of the password managers that I have used. AFAIK, I don't think that it's possible at this point. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: By *protected directories*, do you mean [HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)? If so, Chrome [does](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication) support it (and has for a long time). I’d have to cross-reference the date (Dec,2010) and versions releases, but I’m pretty sure it supported saving HTTPAUTH passwords in 6.0.472.63. (It was discussed in an “ancient” thread about save-password prompts at the Chrome bug database.)

Answer (score 0):

He may have disabled sites in the past. If you click "Show Saved Passwords" from the options and then click the "Exceptions" tab, you can reset the settings per site. 
Next time he visits the site it will ask again.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I went to exceptions and there was nothing listed. The password I am trying to save is not a form password but a protected directory password.